# Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type while using nested structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm using a library developed by Xsens in order to use in my project their mti710-GNSS-INS. This library has the following structures (inside the headers **xbusmessage.h** **xbusparser.h**)

```
struct XbusParser {
    struct XbusParserCallback callbacks;
    struct XbusMessage currentMessage;
    uint16_t payloadReceived;
    uint8_t checksum;
    enum XbusParserState state;
};

struct XbusParserCallback{
    void* (*allocateBuffer)(size_t bufSize);
    void (*deallocateBuffer)(void const* buffer);
    void (*handleMessage)(struct XbusMessage const* message);
};

struct XbusMessage{
    enum XsMessageId mid;
    uint16_t length;
    void* data;
};
```

In my code, I have a `struct XbusParser* xSensBusParser;` as a global variable.
Every time I try to access any field of the "parser struct" I get the following error: **error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type**. Below an example code:

```
bool mti710WakeUp(struct XbusParser* parser, const uint32_t timeout_ms){

    mti710ReadData(parser, sizeof(struct XbusMessage));
    blockingDelay(timeout_ms, TIME_MS); 
    return parser->currentMessage.mid == XMID_Wakeup ? true : false;
}
```

Note that in `mti710ReadData` there is a UART Read function that fills a buffer and then a parsing function that changes the parser fields according to the received buffer.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Creating it might actually make you find the problem.

Comment: @Lundin I already searched on SO but the issue is still there. I'm including both xbusmessage.h xbusparser.h inside my code. What do you mean for "hiding the struct definition in some .c"?

Comment: I'll let the moderator who deleted all comments for unknown reasons answer that.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Lundin in the comments above, there is a hidden struct definition in **xbusparser.c** while in the related header file there is only a

```
struct XbusParser;
```

So I moved the definition from the .c to the .h file and it works well.

Regards.